# How do I get a choice of OS on Start-up?

Tags: ubuntu, windows, dual-boot

I decided I wanted to dual-boot Linux/Win10, each to their own SSD. This, mostly, went off without a hitch. But I'm really tired of having to change the boot order to change OS.

After reading around, I'm pretty sure the issue is that I installed Linux (Peppermint 8) in Legacy and Win10 is in UEFI.

I've tried running Boot-Repair, but it complains it's in a Legacy session and I need to boot it in a UEFI session, which I don't know how to do. I tried a BIOS option of 'Boot USB in EFI Shell' but that didn't seem to work.

Honestly, if there's a way to put Win10 into Legacy mode easily, I'd accept that too.

Answer (score 0):

you could use the bios if it is supported. you can install grub to the mbr and a normal efi boot partition on the windows drive. then configure your bios to enable The boot selection menu. (normally f12 on boot to activate) Most bios systems support this and can be used to boot legacy or uefi boot options.

Comment: will expand with pictures when i get off work but this should work from uefi boot mode. There are a few systems I have found that do not support re-posting to legacy mode on the fly.